# How can I use a word boundary regex in the findstr utility

Tags: regex, findstr

I am searching a folder looking for files which contain the word `car`. This is a sample of the data I'm working with, obtained by using the `findstr` utility - `findstr /s /i /n car *.*`

> interview-290346:1:Drives a similar car to the description.
>
> interview-29316965:3:time.) 'You're nothing but a pack of cards!'
>
> interview-676473:7:The next witness was the Duchess's cook. She carried the pepper-box in
>
> interview-3804339:1:Park's car is red, not blue, and the person on the camera is presumed to be male.  Not considered a suspect.

I want to find the files which contain the word `car`, but not words which contain the substring `car`. I have tried to use the `findstr` utility with the regex `car\b` but I can't work out how to escape it properly. None of the below return any results:

```
findstr /s /i /n car\b *.*
findstr /s /i /n "car\b" *.*
findstr /s /i /n car\\b *.*
findstr /s /i /n car\\\\b *.*
findstr /s /i /n "car\\b" *.*
findstr /s /i /n "car\\\\b" *.*
```

What is the correct way to escape the regex, and is there something else I need to do in order to use it within `findstr`? (I did notice after typing this that the regex will still match words with the `car` substring at the end of the word, but that's ok. My question isn't about what regex to use, but how to escape it for use in `findstr`.)

(If anyone is interested in the context of this question, I'm working through the [Command Line murder mystery](https://github.com/veltman/clmystery).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr), findstr doesn't understand \b. You could  use an inverse class instead, e.g. "car[^a-z]" (untested), although that wouldn't match if "car" was the last thing in the file. (You could maybe invoke *findstr* with a different expression to catch those.)